# Simulating mouse click in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, automation

I'm building a screen scraping utility to automate the population of legacy web forms. After researching Selenium and other automation frameworks, I settled on simply using the C# WebBrower control and so far it's easy to use and working well. One of the webforms, however, utilizes a java-driven navigation pane that I can't control as I would with html elements. Therefore, my plan is to find the screen coordinates of the various navigation elements and simulate mouse clicks.

I found a few relevant posts and was led to try something like this (code below). It doesn't work, though, and I can't figure out why. I've tried passing handles to both the WebBrowser control and its parent form in the ClickOn() call but neither works. I looked at it using Spy++ and it appears that no messages are being triggered. Anyone know what the culprit might be?

Also, I should add that there's no java involved yet. I'm just trying to click on an html button at this point to validate the ClickOn method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(onDocLoaded);
    }

    private void onLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser.Navigate(@"http://www.dummysite.com/");
    }

    void onDocLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        ClickOn(browser.Handle, 899, 463);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessage",  CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool PostMessage1(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg,
      int wParam, int lParam);

    private void ClickOn(IntPtr hControl, int x, int y)
    {
        uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        PostMessage1(hControl, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, x, y);
        PostMessage1(hControl, WM_LBUTTONUP, x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling ClickOn from javascript after window.load event